# Transforming python code to HDL using hls4ml

Tags: python

I am following this tutorial: https://fastmachinelearning.org/hls4ml/setup/QUICKSTART.html
when I give the command:

```
root@ubuntu:~/Desktop/vivado/hls4ml/example-models$ hls4ml convert -c keras-config.yml
hls4ml: command not found
```

What should I do? I tried

```
pip install hls4ml
```

I get this:

```
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: hls4ml in /home/mojito/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /home/mojito/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from hls4ml) (1.16.6)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /home/mojito/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from hls4ml) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in /home/mojito/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from hls4ml) (5.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: h5py in /home/mojito/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from hls4ml) (2.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: onnx>=1.4.0 in /home/mojito/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from hls4ml) (1.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: typing>=3.6.4; python_version < "3.5" in /home/mojito/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from onnx>=1.4.0->hls4ml) (3.7.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf in /home/mojito/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from onnx>=1.4.0->hls4ml) (3.11.3)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.6.2.1 in /home/mojito/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from onnx>=1.4.0->hls4ml) (3.7.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /home/mojito/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from protobuf->onnx>=1.4.0->hls4ml) (44.1.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/hls-fpga-machine-learning/hls4ml.git
$ cd hls4ml/
$ pip install .
```

Git repo: https://github.com/hls-fpga-machine-learning/models .

Also you can use pip as a module: `$ python -m pip <command> [options]`

Comment: mojito@ubuntu:~/Desktop/vivado/hls4ml$ pip install .
...
Installing collected packages: hls4ml
  Attempting uninstall: hls4ml
    Found existing installation: hls4ml 0.2.0
    Uninstalling hls4ml-0.2.0:
      Successfully uninstalled hls4ml-0.2.0
Successfully installed hls4ml-0.2.0
mojito@ubuntu:~/Desktop/vivado/hls4ml$ cd example-models/
mojito@ubuntu:~/Desktop/vivado/hls4ml/example-models$ hls4ml convert -c keras-config.yml
hls4ml: command not found

Comment: What is the output of `python -m pip list` , and also could you try `find / -name hls4ml 2>>/dev/null`